# Android saves session cookies between application launches -- Is this expected?

Tags: android, session, cookies

I have an application in a web view that uses session cookies. (Cookies that get deleted when browser is closed). If I login to my web application, and then kill my Android app and then load the url again, the session cookie still persists. This is NOT what I expected. Is this known behavior?

here is my code:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    String storeUrl = intent.getStringExtra("storeUrl");
    this.webView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView);     
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient()
    {
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url)
        {

        }
    });
    webView.loadUrl(storeUrl);  
}
```

Comment: Please define "kill my app".

Comment: I open up the running apps screen and swipe it away

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Afaik, Android store the cookies in the RAM

> The CookieSyncManager is used to synchronize the browser cookie store between RAM and permanent storage. To get the best performance, browser cookies are saved in RAM

You can clear session cookies pro-grammatically, put this `onBackPressed` method so that when you leave from your application then it will clear the session cookies.

```
CookieManager cm = CookieManager.getInstance(this);
cm.removeSessionCookie();
```

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/CookieManager.html#removeSessionCookie()

Comment: What I am asking though is how session cookies persisting between app launches?

Comment: Cookies remain in RAM until you clear your RAM  or you clear it programmatically. It does not clear when you close your app or re-launch.